# not able to access class methods using the class instance returned by a static method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cypress

I have created a subscriber class to store subscriber details and use a static method to return the instance of the class, but I am not able to set the values using the instance

Here is the subscriber class:

```
let _instance;

export class Subscriber {

    constructor(username, password) {
        this._username = username;
        this._password = password;
    }


    setSubscriberId(subscriberId) {
        cy.log(subscriberId);
        this._subscriberId = subscriberId;
    }

    setSessionId(sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }


    getUserName = () => {
        return this._username;
    }
    getPassword = () => {
        return this._password;
    }

    getSubsciberId() {
        return this._subscriberId;
    }

    getSessionId() {
        return this.sessionId;
    }


    static createSubscriber(username, password) {
        if (!_instance) {
            _instance = new Subscriber(username, password);
        }
        return _intance;
    }

    static getSubscriber() {
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

I am creating a instance of the class in `before` block and accessing the instance in `Given` block

```
before("Create a new subscriber before the tests and set local storage", () => {
    const username = `TestAutomation${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}@sharklasers.com`;
    const password = "test1234";
    subscriberHelpers.createSubscriber(username, password, true).then((response) => {
        cy.log(response);
        Subscriber.createSubscriber(username, password);
        Subscriber.getSubscriber().setSubscriberId(response.Subscriber.Id);
        Subscriber.getSubscriber().setSessionId(response.SessionId);
    }).catch((error) => {
        cy.log(error);
    });
});

Given(/^I launch selfcare app$/, () => {
    cy.launchApp();
});

Given(/^I Set the environemnt for the test$/, () => {
    cy.log(Subscriber.getSubscriber());
    cy.log(Subscriber.getSubscriber().getSubsciberId());
});
```

here is the output on the cypress console

[image: Cypress]

Questions:

1. Why the subscriberID is null even though I am setting it in the `before` block
2. if I print the subscriber Object why am I not seeing subscriberID

Here is the output of subscriber object

[image: subscriber Object]

Comment: You are returning the undefined variable `_intance` from your function. Maybe that should be `_instance`? Also, are you sure you can use `() =>` functions in a class like this?

Answer (score 0):

Properties `username` and `password` are defined synchronously in `before()`, so are present on the object when tested.

But `subscriberId` is obtained asynchronously, so you will need to wait for completion inside the test, e.g

```js
cy.wrap(Subscriber.getSubscriber()).should(function(subscriber){
  expect(subscriber.getSubsciberId()).not.to.be.null
})
```

Refer to [wrap - Objects](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html#Objects) to see how to handle an object with Cypress commands.

and see [should - Differences](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Differences)

> When using a callback function with .should() or .and(), on the other hand, there is special logic to rerun the callback function until no assertions throw within it.

In other words, `should` will retry (up to 5 seconds) until the `expect` inside the callback does not fail (i.e in your case the async call has completed).